# OData 8 - What is the new Input Parameter syntax on an ODataController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata, blazor

For oData 7, this code allowed me to pass an id to my oDataController function.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("Projects({id})")]
    public IActionResult GetProjects([FromODataUri] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        ProjectEntity project = _Db.Projects.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return Ok(_AutoMapper.Map<ProjectDto>(project));
    }
```

After updating to oData8, the route is not found.  What is the new syntax?  There are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Crosman,

Since ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 RC, ODataRouteAttribute is gone. You can use ASP.NET Core routing attributes, for example, HttpGetAttribute, etc.

I have a post that you can refer to:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/